# Постфиксная польская запись С++

Tags: c++, стек, запись, польская-запись

Дано выражение (-a)-(-b). Организовать вычисление этого выражения, используя алгоритм постфиксной польской записи.

- Так будет выглядеть данная запись в стеке?
  -- b 0 - a 0 (читать справа-налево)
- В стек помещается чар или инт?
- И как проводить расчеты?

Answer (score 1):

Как хранить в стеке - в данном случае есть два стека. Один для вычислений, другой хранит саму польскую запись (хотя это уже не стек, а просто очередь).

Стек для вычислений лучше всего делать типа int или double(float).

Запись самого вычисления лучше сделать в обычном векторе строк (хотя можно и в стеке, как удобно). И хранить в "нормальном порядке" (то есть, развернуть). То есть, я бы хранил такое `{"0", "a", "-', "0", "b", "-", "-"}`.

Как выполнять. Код в цикле читает элемент с вектора и смотрит на него. Если это число (первый символ - цифра) - помещает в стек вычислений, если это переменная (a или b в вашем случае, то есть, первый символ - это a..z A..Z) - берет их значение (к примеру, спрашивает у пользователя) и заносит в стек. Если в очереди операция, то извлекает с стека два числа, производит операцию и заносит в стек результат вычислений. В конце работы просто распечатывается вершина стека.

Собственно код, я думаю Вы можете написать самостоятельно.

Answer (score 1):

> Так будет выглядеть данная запись в стеке? `-- b 0 - a 0` (читать справа-налево)

Нет. Эта запись - она не в стеке. Запись - это входная последовательность команд. И она всегда пишется слева-направо!

> В стек помещается чар или инт?

Вы когда в магазине стоимость покупки прикидываете, складываете цены товаров или их названия? Если в жизни вы всегда складываете числа - то откуда вообще взялась идея помещать в стек символы?

> И как проводить расчеты?

Последовательно выполнять входную последовательность команд!

Вот она: `0 a - 0 b - -`

1. Помещаем в стек 0
2. Помещаем туда же значение числа a
3. Забираем из стека два последних числа и вычитаем, результат помещаем обратно в стек
4. Делаем то же самое с командами `0 b -`, в стеке теперь лежат *числа* `(-a)` и `(-b)`
5. Повторяем операцию вычитания еще раз, теперь в стеке лежит только одно число - результат выражения
6. Достаем его из стека и показываем пользователю (либо делаем что-тио другое, в зависимости от того что требуется)